# mplFinance edit x-axis to show seconds

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplfinance

I am wondering if there is a way to have an MPLFinance plot show more keys(time) and seconds as well as minutes. I know you are able to add the minute, but can't find anywhere to add the seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell `mpf.plot()` how you want to format the datetime axis using kwarg `datetime_format=`.  You can use any [**valid strftime string**](https://strftime.org/).

For example, **`datetime_format='%b %d, %H:%M:%S'`** to show hours, minutes, and seconds (along with the month and day) for example, **"Nov 3 14:53:15"**.   Of course, the datetime index of your DataFrame must contain hours, minutes, and seconds, or they may show as zeros: "Nov 3 00:00:00".

Comment: This was very helpful! However, I am also looking to plot more labels. Currently, the chart shows ~5 over an x minute period. I need more like 10 over the same x period. Any chance you know how to solve this as well?

Comment: @Xobiwan  I'm actually working on an enhancement for that presently.  Still it could be another month, or more likely two, because I'm working on other projects too.  I'll see if I can find you a work-around sometime in the next day or two.  If you don't mind setting `show_nontrading=True` for your plots, then it will be easier to implement a workaround.  lmk.

Comment: I apologize for the delay. I will go ahead and set `show_nontrading=True` for the time being. Looking forward to seeing your change.